# How to use Python xlwings to copy a large list of lists to Excel

Tags: python, list, xlwings

I have a lists of lists of length 42, and each list has about 16 items in it. I have noticed that copying the list to excel using xlwings only works for up to 25 lists and anything after that doesn't work, or works sometimes and sometimes doesn't. I have the complete list and code below if anyone would like to reproduce the issue.

```
import xlwings as xw

data = [['1st', '(6)', '29.9', '407m', '22/05/2017', 'GRAC', 'M', '23.76', '23.76', '23.13', '8.62', '0.50', 'Supreme Flash', '1111', '', '$6.60'], ['8th', '(5)', '29.8', '407m', '29/05/2017', 'GRAC', '5', '24.64', '23.52', '23.15', '9.02', '16.00', 'Vision Time', '1788', '', '$17.80'], ['5th', '(3)', '30.3', '305m', '12/06/2017', 'GRAC', '5', '18.25', '17.84', '17.81', '3.30', '5.75', 'Red Red Wine', '7835', '', '$21.60'], ['2nd', '(2)', '30.1', '407m', '07/07/2017', 'GRAC', 'MX', '23.62', '23.57', '22.89', '8.60', '0.75', 'Tictac Cloud', '3222', '', '$24.10'], ['4th', '(4)', '29.9', '407m', '14/07/2017', 'GRAC', '5', '23.58', '23.44', '22.98', '8.67', '2.00', 'Kooringa Theo', '2434', '', '$7.00'], ['8th', '(4)', '29.9', '407m', '24/07/2017', 'GRAC', '5', '24.44', '23.75', '23.03', '8.88', '9.75', 'Myraki', '3458', '', '$10.20'], ['1st', '(1)', '30.4', '407m', '07/08/2017', 'GRAC', '5', '23.41', '23.41', '23.12', '8.52', '3.00', 'Myraki', '11', '', '$8.10'], ['1st', '(7)', '30.4', '407m', '14/08/2017', 'GRAF', '5', '23.53', '23.53', '23.18', '8.62', '0.75', 'Gee Tee Bee', '11', '', '$26.40'], ['4th', '(6)', '30.6', '420m', '22/08/2017', 'LISM', '5', '24.58', '23.97', '23.88', '', '8.75', 'Bazaar Mckenzie', '5444', '', '$12.20'], ['5th', '(8)', '31.7', '407m', '23/10/2017', 'GRAC', '5', '23.86', '23.55', '23.27', '8.71', '4.25', 'Hidden Sniper', '1755', '', '$8.50'], ['3rd', '(8)', '31.3', '407m', '30/10/2017', 'GRAC', '5', '23.68', '23.40', '23.13', '8.63', '4.00', 'Hidden Sniper', '1763', '', '$10.20'], ['1st', '(8)', '30.4', '420m', '14/11/2017', 'LISC', '5', '24.19', '24.19', '23.93', '9.82', '1.50', 'Pavlova Cloud', '2211', '', '$3.60'], ['3rd', '(1)', '30.3', '420m', '21/11/2017', 'LISM', '5', '24.34', '24.12', '24.10', '9.78', '3.00', 'Senor Izmir', '3333', '', '$5.50'], ['6th', '(6)', '30.2', '420m', '28/11/2017', 'LISM', '5', '24.98', '24.16', '24.01', '10.17', '11.75', 'Ace Gambler', '7666', '', '$3.80'], ['5th', '(8)', '30.2', '407m', '04/12/2017', 'GRAF', '5', '23.68', '23.11', '23.11', '8.80', '8.25', 'Slippery Valley', '1665', '', '$12.80'], ['1st', '(8)', '30.1', '411m', '08/12/2017', 'CASC', '4/5', '23.55', '23.55', '23.34', '', '2.25', 'Plane Spotter', '1111', '', '$3.40'], ['1st', '(2)', '30.3', '411m', '15/12/2017', 'CASO', '4/5', '23.29', '23.29', '23.29', '', '2.25', 'Benne Fortuna', '1111', '', '$5.10'], ['3rd', '(5)', '30.4', '407m', '01/01/2018', 'GRAF', '5', '23.68', '23.52', '22.94', '8.66', '2.25', 'Bella Lyndan', '1433', '', '$3.80'], ['5th', '(3)', '30.1', '420m', '09/01/2018', 'LISM', '5', '24.37', '24.00', '23.90', '9.82', '5.25', 'Brightest Star', '4555', '', '$4.30'], ['4th', '(2)', '30.4', '420m', '16/01/2018', 'LISM', '5', '24.60', '24.11', '24.04', '10.28', '7.00', 'Lucky Call', '7644', '', '$6.30'], ['1st', '(1)', '30.2', '407m', '22/01/2018', 'GRAC', '4/5', '23.21', '23.21', '23.20', '8.68', '6.75', 'Soltador', '7211', '', '$3.30'], ['2nd', '(2)', '29.9', '407m', '29/01/2018', 'GRAC', '4/5', '23.36', '23.25', '23.24', '8.59', '1.50', 'Slippery Valley', '7322', '', '$3.60'], ['4th', '(6)', '29.8', '407m', '05/02/2018', 'GRAF', '5', '23.69', '23.18', '23.18', '8.61', '7.25', 'Karaoke Cloud', '1444', '', '$3.10'], ['3rd', '(6)', '30.0', '420m', '13/02/2018', 'LISM', '5', '24.18', '24.01', '24.01', '9.80', '2.25', 'Tranquil Invader', '4333', '', '$5.90'], ['3rd', '(1)', '30.0', '420m', '20/02/2018', 'LISM', '5', '24.23', '24.10', '23.95', '9.86', '1.75', 'Benne Fortuna', '3333', '', '$3.30'], ['2nd', '(4)', '30.0', '420m', '27/02/2018', 'LISM', '5', '24.18', '23.91', '23.91', '9.75', '3.75', 'Oh So Fabio', '3322', '\n$4.70'], ['6th', '(4)', '30.0', '407m', '05/03/2018', 'GRAF', '5', '24.57', '23.63', '23.36', '8.63', '13.25', 'Star Billing', '2676', '', '$5.90'], ['1st', '(4)', '29.8', '407m', '12/03/2018', 'GRAC', '4/5', '23.27', '23.27', '23.08', '8.57', '0.50', 'Senor Izmir', '3321', '', '$8.50'], ['3rd', '(8)', '30.4', '407m', '19/03/2018', 'GRAC', '4/5', '23.24', '23.02', '23.02', '8.58', '3.00', "Freddy's Back", '1633', '', '$17.40'], ['6th', '(5)', '30.6', '420m', '27/03/2018', 'LISM', '5', '24.88', '24.25', '23.97', '10.31', '9.00', 'Kingsbrae Steve', '7666', '', '$4.00'], ['1st', '(3)', '30.4', '407m', '02/04/2018', 'GRAF', '5', '23.17', '23.17', '23.15', '8.54', '1.25', 'Whistler Valley', '2221', '', '$5.60'], ['3rd', '(1)', '30.3', '407m', '09/04/2018', 'GRAC', 'NG', '23.41', '23.13', '23.13', '8.53', '4.00', 'Orara Sal', '4323', '', '$3.60'], ['5th', '(3)', '30.0', '520m', '17/04/2018', 'LISM', '4/5', '30.67', '30.30', '30.06', '4.53', '5.25', 'Kulu Turkey', '2455', '', '$4.70'], ['5th', '(5)', '30.2', '411m', '27/04/2018', 'CASO', '5', '24.26', '23.86', '23.18', '', '5.75', 'Our Cavalier', '5555', '', '$4.30'], ['6th', '(3)', '31.4', '305m', '13/08/2018', 'GRAC', '4/5', '18.29', '17.79', '17.31', '3.31', '7.00', "Here's Molly", '8856', '', '$7.60'], ['1st', '(6)', '31.6', '305m', '20/08/2018', 'GRAC', '5', '17.66', '17.66', '17.66', '3.19', '1.25', 'Sandler', '1111', '', '$3.30'], ['1st', '(3)', '31.6', '420m', '28/08/2018', 'LISM', '4/5', '24.46', '24.46', '24.05', '9.95', '2.00', "Don't Seamus", '1111', '', '$2.00'], ['7th', '(7)', '31.6', '407m', '03/09/2018', 'GRAF', '4/5', '24.05', '23.48', '23.39', '8.72', '8.25', 'Kooringa Molly', '4667', '', '$6.50'], ['6th', '(4)', '31.4', '411m', '07/09/2018', 'CASC', '5', '23.90', '23.49', '23.15', '', '5.75', 'Nitro Beach', '6566', '', '$5.70'], ['4th', '(3)', '31.1', '420m', '11/09/2018', 'LISM', '4/5', '24.33', '23.91', '23.80', '9.78', '6.00', 'Blue Max', '4444', '', '$10.10'], ['5th', '(3)', '31.3', '411m', '14/09/2018', 'CASO', '5', '24.01', '23.25', '22.97', '', '10.75', 'Kingsbrae Steve', '7755', '\n$3.60']]

wb = xw.Book('example.xlsm')

sht = wb.sheets["Sheet1"]

sht.clear()
sht.range('A1').value = data[1:26]
```

The above code works and copies each list to successive row. However it doesnt work when I change the 26 to any number above. Also the code doesn't work if my starting index is 0, for example  `sht.range('A1').value = data[0:5]`How can I get this working properly?

Comment: why dont you create a dataframe from the list of lists and then convert into excel sheet.. much simpler i guess

Comment: @SarthakNegi I need the code to update a spreadsheet in real time that's why I'm using xlwings

Comment: can you explain "real time" ?

Comment: @SarthakNegi I mean I can have the spreadsheet open and soon as I click run the sheet is instantly updated. I don't have to have it closed to update it like other python packages that interact with excel.

Comment: `f` doesn't seem to be defined in your code - did you mean to put `data` there?

Comment: [Edit] your Question and explain `f[..]`. Instead of `sht.range(...).value = ...` try to do it Row by Row.

Comment: @Stuart thanks I've edited

Comment: @stovfl Let me give that a go

Comment: @stovfl Do you reckon its some form of bug in xlwings? As its clearly not working according to the docs,

Comment: I guess some limitations, so reduce the amount of data, it's worth a try

Answer (score 4):

Ok I've realised xlwings certainly struggles and is unpredictable with lists. For anyone having this issue, simply convert the list to a dataframe and it works as expected. Sample code below:

```
import xlwings as xw
import pandas as pd

data = [['1st', '(6)',...]] #View complete list above

wb = xw.Book('example.xlsm')

sht = wb.sheets["Sheet1"]

sht.clear()

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

sht.range("A1").value = df
```

Answer (score 3):

All lists/tuples that represent rows must be of the same length. It's a known limitation and there should be an appropriate error message with one of the next releases, see the [issue](https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/xlwings/issues/941).

Your answer works as numpy arrays or pandas dataframes are always regular arrays.